# How can i benchmark my SQL and PHP code?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, benchmarking

I have problems because i don't really know how I can test my code and sql ( mysql ) to see how long SQL queries and PHP functions /code take to run.

Does anyone here know where I can find these tools?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For PHP code, you can use [xdebug for profiling](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler). You'll need a frontend to read the trace data as well. If you're on windows, you can use [WinCacheGrind](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wincachegrind/). For other OS'es you can use either [kCacheGrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/) (Lots of features, but a bit scary for beginners) or [WebGrind](http://code.google.com/p/webgrind/) (Much simpler and nicer looking).

For Mysql, you can use [maatkit](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-query-profiler.html) for profiling multiple queries, and to analyse a specific query, you should use [EXPLAIN](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/07/24/extended-explain/).

Answer (score 1):

This is called profiling. [XDebug](http://www.xdebug.org/), [APD](http://pecl.php.net/package/apd) and probably some other packages provide this functionality.

Comment: Xbebug i don't like it, its not soe good to bechmark i ges, :/ i dont know APD.

Comment: @NeoNmaN Out of curiosity, what don't you like about xdebug's profiler?

Answer (score 1):

The search keyword you want is "**profiler**".

There's several PHP profilers out there; [XDebug](http://www.xdebug.org/), [PHPEd Profiler](http://www.nusphere.com/products/php_profiler.htm), [APD](http://pecl.php.net/package/apd), [DBG](http://www.php-debugger.com/dbg/), and [PQP](http://particletree.com/features/php-quick-profiler/), just to name a few.

I've used XDebug on several occasions and though it can be a little annoying to get up and running it does a pretty decent job. Just follow the [installations docs](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/install) and you should be fine.

Comment: i have read about PQP before but i dont understand to make it to work, :/